# Inherited class methods return parent object. Need to make it return object of child class

Tags: python, oop, pyspark

I am trying to check the feasibility of subclassing the PySpark DataFrame class to add extra reusable methods across my work.

```
class EnhancedDataframe(DataFrame):
   def __init__(self, df):
     super().__init__(df._jdf,df.sql_ctx)

  def notNullCount(self,col_name):
     return self.filter(col(col_name).isNotNull()).count()
```

The problem is if I use this to create new dataframes, whenever I use a parent method which returns parent type object, my new class methods won't be available anymore with that.

So, how to return an object of child class for all parent methods. One option that I consider using is the `__getattribute__` function and try to return child object by enclosing it in the child class name. Do we have any other options? What I am trying to do is it feasible?

Comment: You mean you want `notNullCount` to return an `EnhancedDataframe`? Did you try passing the result of that method to instantiate a new `EnhancedDataframe` ?

Comment: I haven't looked at the `pandas` source, but I think it likely builds new dataframes from `pandas.DataFrame` when, to be fully polymorphic, it should build them from `self.__class__`.

Comment: @ddejohn  has what may be the best solution. But it would be expensive to create the new dataframe. You could go old school and make your method a regular function outside of the class definition that takes the dataframe as its first parameter. It really wouldn't have to change (except rename "self" to "df").

Comment: Agreed, it'd be better as a function (or many functions it sounds like) to which you can pass dataframes. I see no reason wanting "extra reusable methods across my work" means you have to bother with trying to subclass dataframes, unless you have plans for implementing dunder methods for certain operations on multiple dataframes?

Comment: No. I mean the base class methods for example join, filter return base class object which means it's not an object of my inherited class and I cannot call my reusable methods in the first place. I am just trying to see the feasibility of building something like this. Kind of exploration. We already have some reusable code in regular functions. If it is too much of performance loss, then I am gonna stick with regular functions.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem. Its easy to break polymorphism by building new instances using the class name you know (`pandas.DataFrame`) rather than the class of the current object (`self.__class__`). From the behavior, it looks like pandas does the former instead of that latter.

You can make your method a function outside of the class definition that takes the dataframe to work on as a parameter.

```
def notNullCount(df, col_name):
     return df.filter(col(col_name).isNotNull()).count()
```

This is a common way to add functionality to classes. But it suffers from a similar problem with polymorphism - its not easy to have further subclasses override them.

Comment: That's right. Regular functions seem to be much easier to use. I was looking forward to use class methods kind of like pythonic way.